# I would Like to know what -sb and awk '{print $1}' role in this command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, size

```
subdirectory_size=$(du -sb "$entry" | awk '{print $1}').
```

I would Like to know what `-sb` and `awk '{print $1}'` role in this command.

Comment: Have a look in the manual page of the command *du*: [https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The -sb tells the DU (Disk Utilization)/comand to show a summary (-s) of usage in bytes (-b)

The Awk parameter is taking only thr first part of each line returned by thr information fed into it.